# How to use separated load balancers for frontend and backend in ECS?

Tags: terraform, load-balancing, amazon-ecs

I have the following terraform configuration for a load balancer running in ECS AWS for my django app container deployed in ECS:

```
resource "aws_lb" "api" {
  name               = "${local.prefix}-api"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets = [
    aws_subnet.public_a.id,
    aws_subnet.public_b.id
  ]

  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb_api.id]

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "api" {
  name        = "${local.prefix}-api"
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id
  target_type = "ip"
  port        = 8000

  health_check {
    path = "/admin/login/"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "api" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.api.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "api_https" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.api.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"

  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert.certificate_arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.api.arn
  }
}


resource "aws_security_group" "lb_api" {
  description = "Allow access to Application Load Balancer"
  name        = "${local.prefix}-lb-api"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 8000
    to_port     = 8000
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

I have an almost identical file for the react frontend container. The only differences are the replacement of the word "api" for "frontend", the target group port (which is 80 in the case of frontend load balancer), and the health check path (just "/" for frontend)

When I deploy only the API, I can normally access the application on browser. However, when I add the frontend load balancer, I  cannot access the frontend in the browser (error "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"). The django application kept working but after a while, it also went down.

I look at the ECS UI and I note that the cluster, the task and the containers are running without problems. But I keep getting errors in health checks. I think this error is probably related to the ports mapping. But the mappings are consistent with the [container-definitions](https://gist.github.com/lucascr91/f16c0a198dd369b431c51035ea697c32) file.

What is the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

so from the sounds of it , it appears that you are deploying your application using only a task .

One way to get ingress traffic to container is by using an ecs service , you then atttacht the relevant task definition to it and you would define the loadbalancer config on the ecs service to integrate with your tasks container .

the nice thing about the ecs services is that you can then introduce deployment strategies and autoscaling of tasks for HA .

to do it , you would configure the following in the ecs service :

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "api" {
  # ... other configurations
  load_balancer {

      target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.api.arn
      container_name   = "api" # Name of the container to associate with the load balancer (as it appears in a container definition).
      container_port   = 8000  # (Required) Port on the container to associate with the load balancer.
  }
}
```

keep the target group as ip type and use the container port on the target group ... , ecs will handle the registering/attachment into the target group. You may want to alter some target group configuration for the health probes and degistration configs as each app is different. Also for your healthchecks , make sure that those paths are reachable and return a status code of 200 otherwise set up a dedicated path for healthchecks. You can always change the return status code on the target group health check config to be something like 200-399.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html

the above link gives some idea as to what you can do with this sort of approach and then there's an alternative approach (below link) which is far more complex to implement and manage which uses nginx and nlb as an ingress gateway .

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/load-balancing-amazon-ecs-services-with-a-kubernetes-ingress-controller-style-approach/

hope this helps